# How to get CPU info in C on Linux, such as number of cores?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, cpu

Is it possible to get such info by some API or function, rather than parsing the `/proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: Duplicate question. see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304841/236062

Answer (score 12):

From `man 5 proc`:

> ```
>    /proc/cpuinfo
>           This is a collection of CPU and  system  architecture  dependent
>           items,  for  each  supported architecture a different list.  Two
>           common  entries  are  processor  which  gives  CPU  number   and
>           bogomips;  a  system  constant  that is calculated during kernel
>           initialization.  SMP machines have information for each CPU.
> ```

Here is sample code that reads and prints the info to console, [stolen from forums](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-get-cmdline-from-proc-filesystem-772529/) - It really is just a specialized `cat` command.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   FILE *cpuinfo = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo", "rb");
   char *arg = 0;
   size_t size = 0;
   while(getdelim(&arg, &size, 0, cpuinfo) != -1)
   {
      puts(arg);
   }
   free(arg);
   fclose(cpuinfo);
   return 0;
}
```

Please note that you need to parse and compare the `physical id`, `core id` and `cpu cores` to get an accurate result, if you really care about the number of CPUs vs. CPU cores. Also please note that if there is a `htt` in `flags`, you are running a hyper-threading CPU, which means that your mileage may vary.

Please also note that if you run your kernel in a virtual machine, you only see the CPU cores dedicated to the VM guest.

Comment: Curious question. Who updates this file?

Comment: @RamBhat - it is not _file_ in general sense. See the Wikipedia [article about procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)

Comment: I found this article very helpful, in terms of understanding the /proc/cpuinfo file - http://www.richweb.com/cpu_info

Answer (score 10):

You can use this for mostly all kind of linux distro

For C code

```
 num_cpus = sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN );
```

(In QNX systems , you can use `num_cpus = sysinfo_numcpu()`)

For shell scripting, you can use `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

or use `lscpu` or `nproc` commands in linux

Comment: this is the most 'programmatical', possibly simplest way; although man sysconf() specifies that the value "may not be standard"

Comment: For people who came here looking for help with QNX - there's no such method in base qnx660 as sysinfo_numcpu()

Answer (score 5):

[`libcpuid`](http://libcpuid.sourceforge.net/index.html) provides a simple API which will directly return all the CPU features, including number of cores. To get the number of cores at runtime, you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libcpuid.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (!cpuid_present()) {
        printf("Sorry, your CPU doesn't support CPUID!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    struct cpu_raw_data_t raw; 
    struct cpu_id_t data;     

    if (cpuid_get_raw_data(&raw) < 0) { 
        printf("Sorry, cannot get the CPUID raw data.\n");
        printf("Error: %s\n", cpuid_error());
        return -2;
    }

    if (cpu_identify(&raw, &data) < 0) {    
        printf("Sorrry, CPU identification failed.\n");
        printf("Error: %s\n", cpuid_error());
        return -3;
    }

    printf("Processor has %d physical cores\n", data.num_cores);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The library did not compile out-of-the-box on my linux box.

Comment: @Kimvais: All I can say is that it works for me.

Comment: yep, didn't really troubleshoot, just did `configure && make && sudo make install` and make failed, might be something really simple :)

Answer (score 4):

Read `/proc/cpuinfo`

**Sample Output**

```
processor   : 0
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5410  @ 2.33GHz
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
processor   : 1
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5410  @ 2.33GHz
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
processor   : 2
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5410  @ 2.33GHz
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
processor   : 3
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5410  @ 2.33GHz
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
```

[show_cpuinfo](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c#L64) is the function which actually implements the `/proc/cpuinfo` functionality

Answer (score 2):

Add following line in your source code..

```
system("cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l");
```

This will print number of cpus in your system.
And if you want to use this output of this system call in your program than use popen system call.

Comment: No its not, this will count the hyperthreads as well, please read - http://www.richweb.com/cpu_info for detailed info decoding /proc/cpuinfo file.

Comment: Threads: cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -c "cpu cores"   ## Cores: cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -m 1 "cpu cores"|cut -d ":" -f 2

Answer (score 1):

Parse the file /proc/cpuinfo. This'll give you lot of details about the CPU. Extract the relevant fields into your C/C++ file.

Comment: any libraries suitable to read the file ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Either you must parse cpuinfo file, or some library will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your flavor of Linux you will get different results from /proc/cpuid.

This works for me on CentOS for getting total number of cores.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -w cores | sed -e 's/\t//g' | awk '{print $3}' | xargs | sed -e 's/\ /+/g' | bc
```

The same doesn't work in Ubuntu. For Ubuntu you can use the following command.

```
nproc
```

Comment: Useless usage of `cat`. The following will work just fine: `grep -m1 "cores" /proc/cpuinfo | tr -d '[a-z]:[:space:]'`

Comment: This is for use on a shell. OP asked how to do this programmatically in the C language, not in a shell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever seen the output of this shell command "cat /proc/cpuinfo"? I think there you can get out all the information that you need.
To read the information in a C program I would prefer the file manipulation functions like fopen, fgets and so on.