# How to check CPU name, model, speed on Windows/Linux C?

Tags: c, linux, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-speed

I would like to get some infos with C about hardware:

1. how many CPU's I have
2. how many cores have each of them
3. how many logical cores have every core in every CPU
4. CPU name + model
5. CPU speed + frequency
6. CPU architecture (x86, x64)

I know that on Linux-like OS I can parse `/proc/cpuinfo` but since its not an ordinary file, I think its unsafe. Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine?lq=1) answer on SO but it doesnt give me EVERY info I need. Should I call `cat /proc/cpuinfo > file.txt` and then parse `file.txt`? I know about `cpuid.h` (Im using GCC) but ca't find any doc about this header (anyway - is it a good idea to use it?)

Comment: What do you mean "unsafe"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux procfs's fake files can behave very problematically. The kernel falsely reports them as regular files, but they don't behave as regular files are required to on a conforming POSIX system. For an example, see http://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2013/05/05/9. I suspect you've heard similar reports and this is where your concern is coming from.

With that said, as far as I know, all of the bad behavior of the fake "regular files" in `/proc` pertains only to writing. For reading they should behave sufficiently similar to actual regular files that you can just read them however you like and not worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, you'll want the [`GetSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function; [Microsoft has an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). On Linux, `/proc/cpuinfo` is perfectly "safe", whatever that means, but there's already [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629850/how-to-get-cpu-info-in-c-on-linux-such-as-number-of-cores).

Comment: Call GetNativeSystemInfo if yours is a 32-bit app.

Answer (score 0):

If you care only about intel-compatible CPUs you could use the assembler instruction

```
cpuid
```

either as inline asm or as a separate asm object file.

For example, to check the vendor you would use function 0:

```
xor eax, eax  ; load eax with function 0
cpuid         ; call cpuid
```

Now the vendor ID is located in the registers `ebx, ecx, edx`. Similar functions exist to read all other information.

For more information read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID)