# C- displaying CPU info using kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I've recently learned about kernel modules and I was thinking on how to create one that does what `cat /proc/cpuinfo` does.

Is it possible to do this without opening/reading the file directly (fread)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you try to prepare some example(s) and ask more specific question please?

Comment: Possible [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629850/how-to-get-cpu-info-in-c-on-linux-such-as-number-of-cores). But can't you get the cpu info directly from the processor itself?

Answer (score 0):

/proc/cpuinfo output is generated by kernel code; you can check that code and do the same in your kernel module.

Code is located in fs/proc/cpuinfo.c

It references 'cpuinfo_op' object that is provided by architecture-dependent code, try 'grep cpuinfo_op arch' from toplevel directory of kernel source to locate it.